# How can I add a meta[] to my custom post type and search by term with the Rest API?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, post-meta, rest-api

I just started to use the Rest API and I want to get all posts that belong to a certain taxonomy and term(s) within that taxonomy. That part is working now.

Then I want the those posts to have a meta[] with their fields. I found multiple articles about this but the code did not seem to work. The meta[] is still empty. I want it to add all the fields in there. I'm sure that they have meta because I managed to do it in the old legacy way and that worked.

https://torquemag.io/2018/02/rest-api-custom-fields-revisited/

https://n8finch.com/getting-post-meta-wp-rest-api/

I also noticed that the response is an object, shouldn't it be json?

**Ajax Request**

```
function do_make_rest_api_call()
{
    return '<script>
        $.ajax({
             url: "/wp-json/wp/v2/verhuur?productcategorie=413&per_page=100",
             type: "GET",
        }).then(response => {
            console.log(typeof response);
            console.log(response);
            var json = JSON.parse(response);
            console.log(json);
        });

    </script>';
}
add_shortcode('first_rest_api_call', 'do_make_rest_api_call');
```

**Field Register(register individual fields, I want all the fields in the meta[])**

```
add_action('rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_field('verhuur', 'product', array(
        'get_callback' => function ($post_arr) {
            return get_post_meta($post_arr['id'], 'product', true);
        },
    ));
    register_rest_field('verhuur', 'voorraad', array(
        'get_callback' => function ($post_arr) {
            return get_post_meta($post_arr['id'], 'voorraad', true);
        },
    ));
    register_rest_field('verhuur', 'ex_btw', array(
        'get_callback' => function ($post_arr) {
            return get_post_meta($post_arr['id'], 'ex_btw', true);
        },
    ));
    register_rest_field('verhuur', 'incl_btw', array(
        'get_callback' => function ($post_arr) {
            return get_post_meta($post_arr['id'], 'incl_btw', true);
        },
    ));
    register_rest_field('verhuur', 'groeps_nmr', array(
        'get_callback' => function ($post_arr) {
            return get_post_meta($post_arr['id'], 'groeps_nmr', true);
        },
    ));
    register_rest_field('verhuur', 'bestel_code', array(
        'get_callback' => function ($post_arr) {
            return get_post_meta($post_arr['id'], 'bestel_code', true);
        },
    ));
    register_rest_field('verhuur', 'datum_aangepast', array(
        'get_callback' => function ($post_arr) {
            return get_post_meta($post_arr['id'], 'datum_aangepast', true);
        },
    ));
});
```

Comment: Have you read [this](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/modifying-responses/#working-with-registered-meta-in-the-rest-api)? Because you probably want to use `register_post_meta()`.

Comment: Sorry, I meant [`register_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_meta/)... 